# Python - Download a file from asp form

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping

I am totally new to Python Scripting. I have been trying to come up with some code which could help me, but I was unsuccessful. Problem is I have to download files from this link [Link 1](http://www.pmd.gov.pk/cp/display.asp) when I choose date and time then hit the download button, the url becomes http://www.pmd.gov.pk/cp/displaydata.asp and the required file is shown. I want to write a python scrpit which can iterate over the dates and times and can download the data from resulted webpage to a text file. If anyone could help me, I ll be very thankful.

## Update

this is what i have done so far, but I am unable to go further. any help?
at the moment it gives me this error
"IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: '*5/9/2016*0000.txt'"

```
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("http://www.pmd.gov.pk/cp/display.asp")
br.select_form(nr=0)

controlDate = br.form.find_control("dat")
controlTime = br.form.find_control("Tim")

for Date in controlDate.items:
    for Time in controlTime.items:
        #print "Saving " str(Date)+str(Time)+".txt"
            synoptic = (br.submit()).read()
            textFile = open(str(Date)+str(Time)+".txt", 'w')
            textFile.write(synoptic)
            textFile.close()

print "***FINISHED***"
```

## Update 2

I have improved the code a little more, but still it is not working properly. It keeps downloading the same file again and again. Can anybody help please?

```
import datetime
#adil ="5-9-2016"
#dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(adil, '%m-%d-%Y')
#print '{0}{1}{2:02}'.format(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day % 100)

from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("http://www.pmd.gov.pk/cp/display.asp")
br.select_form(nr=0)
form = br.form #
controlDate = br.form.find_control("dat")
controlTime = br.form.find_control("Tim")

for Date in controlDate.items:
    dtt = str(Date)
    try:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dtt, '%m/%d/%Y')
    except:
        pass
    try:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dtt, '*%m/%d/%Y')
    except:
        pass
    #if Date.name == str(dt.strftime('%m'))+'/'+str(dt.strftime('%d'))+'/'+str(dt.strftime('%Y')):
    if Date.name == str(Date):
        Date.selected = True
        for Time in controlTime.items:
            tt = str(Time)
            try:
                ttt = datetime.datetime.strptime(tt, '%H%M')
            except:
                pass
            try:
                ttt = datetime.datetime.strptime(tt, '*%H%M')
            except:
                pass
            #if Time.name == str(Time):
            #Time.selected = Time.name
            #form['Tim'] = str(Time)
            if Time.name == str(ttt.strftime('%H'))+str(ttt.strftime('%M')):
                Time.selected = True
                synoptic = (br.submit()).read()
                #timeName= "%s%s" %(ttt.hour, ttt.minute)
                textFile = open(str(dt.strftime('%Y'))+str(dt.strftime('%m'))+str(dt.strftime('%d'))+str(ttt.strftime('%H'))+str(ttt.strftime('%M'))+"syn.txt", 'w')
                textFile.write(synoptic)
                textFile.close()
            else:
                break
print "***FINISHED***"
```

## Update 2 [Solved]

Here is the solution to my own problem. I wanted to download the required files after choosing dates and times from a form. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue May 10 14:15:41 2016

@author: MuhammadAdilJaved
"""
import re
import time
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.open("http://www.pmd.gov.pk/cp/display.asp")
br.select_form(nr=0)
form = br.form #
controlDate = br.form.find_control("dat")
controlTime = br.form.find_control("Tim")
backdays = 1            #for how many days in back you want to download data, max. 15
start_time = time.time()
dateList = []
dateListPMD = []

timeList = ['0000', '0300', '0600', '0900', '1200', '1500', '1800', '2100']

#Visit "http://www.pmd.gov.pk/cp/display.asp" and put the available dates in List below
#dateList = ['5/10/2016','5/9/2016',\
#           '5/8/2016','5/7/2016',\
#           '5/6/2016','5/5/2016',\
#           '5/4/2016','5/3/2016',\
#           '5/2/2016','5/1/2016',\
#           '4/30/2016','4/29/2016',\
#           '4/28/2016','4/27/2016',\
#           '4/26/2016']

for item in controlDate.items:
        dateListPMD.append(item.name)

for date in dateListPMD[0:int(backdays)]:
    dateList.append(date)

print "**** Downloading data for following dates: ****"
print dateList
#short dateList for debugging
#dateList = ['5/10/2016','5/9/2016']
#dateList = ['5/10/2016']

i = 0   #for DATE Loop
ii = 0  #for TIME Loop
count = 0 #to calculate no of files Downloaded
for dt in dateList:
    br.open("http://www.pmd.gov.pk/cp/display.asp")
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    form = br.form #
    controlDate = br.form.find_control("dat")
    controlTime = br.form.find_control("Tim")
    for item in controlDate.items:
        if item.name == dt:
            item.selected = True
            dtFileName = dt.translate(None, '!@#$/')
            print "Required DATE found i.e "
            print item.name, dt
            print "DATE loop # ", i
            i = i+1
            for dti in timeList:
                br.open("http://www.pmd.gov.pk/cp/display.asp")
                br.select_form(nr=0)
                form = br.form #
                controlDate = br.form.find_control("dat")
                controlTime = br.form.find_control("Tim")

                for item in controlDate.items:  #
                    if item.name == dt:         #
                        for item2 in controlTime.items:
                            if item2.name == dti:
                                print "Require TIME found & Downloading File i.e "
                                print item2.name, dti
                                print "TIME loop # ", ii
                                ii = ii + 1
                                item.selected = True                        
                                item2.selected = True
                                synoptic = (br.submit()).read()
                                soup = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', synoptic)            
                                textFile = open(str(dtFileName)+str(dti)+'.txt', 'wb')
                                textFile.write(soup)
                                textFile.close()
                                count = count + 1
                            else:
                                #print "Required TIME NOT found"
                                print item2.name, dti
        else:
            #print "Required DATE NOT found"
            print item.name, dt


elapsed_time = (time.time() - start_time)/60
print "*****************************"
print "Total Elapsed Time: ", round(elapsed_time,2), " Mins."
print "Total Files Downloaded: ", str(count)
print "*****  F I N I S H E D  *****"
```

Comment: Your first programming question then would be how do I download a web page given a known url.  Here is where you can start  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python  This is not the only way to do so, I use Python requests so there are lots of alternatives - find an example of one start coding it and when you run into a problem bring some code back here and ask a specific coding question

Comment: hi thanks for the prompt reply. Can you please have a look at the above code and see why its not working the way i wanted. Thanks :)